Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3}(x-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt)$
Calculate the limit of $L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3}(x-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt)$. I am aware of the technique to get $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and have tried something similar, leaving $F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ and getting $F'(s)=\frac{e^-2xs(cos(2x)+sin(2x))-1}{1+s^2}$, from here, I apply the limit and get $F(0)=0$.
Now, it seems pretty logic that it is $0$ because the interval of integration gets smaller and smaller, but I am not sure if this is the way because then $L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty$

Use L'Hôpital's rule.

Hint: you can Taylor expand the sine near $0$ to work out the leading terms of the integral.

HINT
What about Taylor series?
Since
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{5!} - \ldots
\end{align*}
It results that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t = 2x - \frac{(2x)^{3}}{3!3} + \frac{(2x)^{5}}{5!5} - \ldots
\end{align*}
Consequently, it is possible to conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x^{3}}\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t\right) = \frac{1}{x^{3}}\left(\frac{(2x)^{3}}{3!3!} + o(x^{4})\right)
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

@Átila_Correia as I said to Julio, an extremely simpler perspective, thank you so much, I can take it from here.

@MiguelCG you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

The limit is not equal to $+\infty$.
A simpler way to find its value is  using (repeteadly) L'Hôpital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which give us $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{x-\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2x-\sin(2x)}{6x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2-2\cos(2x)}{18x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{4\sin(2x)}{36x}=\dfrac{8}{36}=\dfrac{2}{9}$$
where the last limit follows from the famous $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$.

@Julio_Puerta thanks fot the extremely simpler perspective. I knew there was something wrong with my argument.

You could use L'hospital rule but it will take a while to finish. The quickest way would be to use the Maclaurin expansion for $\sin t$, and then integrate term by term and use asymptote Big O method and you will quickly see the answer which is $\dfrac{8}{3\cdot 3!} = \dfrac{4}{9}$.
